# redirecting output of /dev/fb0 to /dev/fb2

Tags: embedded, arm, framebuffer, ios

I am using IMX6 Saberauto board on Linux OS. I have 2 displays primary is `HDMI` and secondary is `LVDS`. I want to run 2 applications.

One QT on primary display, which I am able to do. Second application is airplay application I want this application to run on seondary display ie `/dev/fb2`. But I am not able to do that.

It is coming on primary display only. Please let me know the command to direct airplay output to `/dev/fb2`.